# Checkbox field, displaying li with different classes

Tags: ee2, list

Nice to see a Stack site for EE. Used S Overflow many times in past, and has always been much help.

Anyhow, heres my first question...

I have a site that lists dog walks. I have a checkbox field for the walks channel. Users submit walks via a safecracker form, and the checkbox field is used for users to select certain features present at the walk.

At the moment I display the field on the single entry view page, using the following...

```
<strong class="heading">Walk Features:</strong>
                <ul>
                  {walk_features}
                    <li>
                      <span>{item}</span>
                      <a href="{site_url}walk_location_features" target="_blank">Find out more</a>
                    </li>
                  {/walk_features}
                </ul>
```

This produces me a simple list on front end. Now I want to spice up that list slightly, by having a different icon/image & description for each option (contained within the checkbox field.)

So I need to output (HTML) something like:

```
<ul class="features">
<li class="option1">
    <h3>Option 1</h3>
    <p>A short description of option one</p>
</li>
<li class="option2">
    <h3>Option 2</h3>
    <p>A short description of option two</p>
</li>
etc
```

I'm just not quite sure on how to get to that from my checkbox field. I have had P&T checkbox field & Low Options suggested, however I am still unclear as to how I can get it from the current field.

I have over 130 entries which use this field, and was hoping that I could output it directly from the existing field. I could add a new field if necessary, and go through transferring the data, but I obviously would like t avoid that if possible! Any help greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest switching the field over to P&T Checkboxes or Radio Button (if you only want them to select one option). In the settings I would specify an option value separately from it's label:

```
option_one : Option 1
option_two : Option 2
option_three : Option 3
```

Then in your template use the option value as the class name:

```
<ul>
  {walk_features}
    <li class="{option}">
      <span>{option_name}</span>
      <a href="{site_url}walk_location_features" target="_blank">Find out more</a>
    </li>
  {/walk_features}
</ul>
```

Since you have 130 entries already, I suggest using a SQL query to find/replace all the entries with the new values. Be sure to backup your DB before doing this.

```
UPDATE
exp_channel_data
SET field_id_X = replace(field_id_X,'Option 1','option_one');
```

**UPDATE**
To add a short description instead of a link:

```
<ul>
  {walk_features}
    <li class="{option}">
      <span>{option_name}</span>

      {if "{option}" == "option_one"}
        short description about Option 1
      {/if}

      {if "{option}" == "option_two"}
        short description about Option 2
      {/if}
      ...

    </li>
  {/walk_features}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for that reply. That is what I have had suggested. (Although I didn't know about the SQL Query find/replace.)

Now this option works, apart from one part.

Before, I had a the link to "Find out more", which was the same for each option, but I am looking at changing that to a short description of the option, as opposed to a link to another page.
Any thoughts on how I can change that based on each option?

(There are eight options in total, and each one will have a different accompanying 1-2 lines explaining it.)

Comment: Will the short description be editable in the channel entries?

Comment: No, it will be 1-2 lines, specific to that option.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Brilliant, thought there would be some way via conditionals. I shall have a look now on my dev site and report back! Thanks.

Comment: Hmmm, well for some reason this doesn't seem to be working.
I've tried (a slightly modified) version on my dev site. Basically leaving the li class option out for now, but I'm getting nothing displayed?

Comment: Hmm, strange, seems to be an issue regarding the tag pair. When I use the single tag, it outputs the options that have been selected. Using a tag pair, nothing.

Comment: Go to Add-Ons > Extensions, and make sure you've clicked the "Enable Extensions?" button.

Comment: Haha! Yep what a donut! Was making me go a bit mad! All seems to be working now. This should hopefully see me through now! Many thanks!

However I do have another question! With regards to the  SQL find/replace, not sure how to do that? Any documentation or example anywhere that might help?

Comment: You can run that query in a database management application like phpMyAdmin, Sequel Pro or Navicat. First you'll need to find out the ID of the custom field by viewing the custom field group it's within (left column is the ID). Then just update the SQL statement above with the correct ID in place of X `field_id_X` and do a find and replace for each value you want to update. If you don't have access to a tool like that, then you can always run it right from the CP > Tools > Data > SQL Manager > Database Query Form. Make sure to backup first!

Comment: That's brilliant. I've got Sequel Pro, only ever used it for checking priorities/orders. I shall work through it with care! Many thanks for your help!